# Translation of "sounds good"

Tags: traduction, formulation-idiomatique

> — A: "Let's meet tonight at 8pm."
>
> — B: "Sounds good!"

What would be a good translation of "Sounds good"? Google Translate suggests "Ça m'a l'air bien", but I'm not sure if it's too formal.

> — A: Retrouvons-nous ce soir à 8h.
>
> — B: Ça m'a l'air bien !

Comment: In addition to the good suggestions given so far, there's also ["Ça me dit {bien}](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120303082607AAKHsuA)," which like Jlente's "Ça me semble/paraît bien" and Evpok's "Ça me va," is also somewhat similar to the construction of the expression suggested by *Google Translate*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you asking for is essentially an informal synonym for *d'accord*. There are quite a lot of them, as you might imagine, but the most notable would be in my opinion

- *OK*
- *Ça marche*
- *Ça roule*
- *Nickel*

Or the more neutral

- *Ça me va*
- *Bien*
- *D'accord*
- *Parfait*

Answer (score 8):

I'm an intermediate learner in French myself.  I'm not sure about the direct translation of that expression; If focusing on getting the meaning across, I'd go with "ça marche" (that works) or "bonne idée" (good idea), or to get closer to the construction of that expression, "Ça me semble/paraît bien" (seems good to me).

Comment: Toutes ces expressions sont acceptables comme traductions de "sounds good", certaines sont d'un registre plus soigné (ça me semble bien), tandis que d'autres sont plus familières (ça marche!). You could edit your answer by removing "I'm not sure", since they perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how close you want to be to the nuance. If you just want to acknowledge, any of the possibilities mentioned so far is fine.

But if you really want to nail it down, "sounds good" means: "I believe it's a good idea", hence "I do not see any issue".

The closest translation that comes to my mind is:

> Ça me paraît bien.

or, as Google Translate correctly suggested:

> Ça m'a l'air bien.

or:

> Ça peut aller.

No, it is not formal, because "ça" belongs more to spoken language. To be formal it would have to be:

> Cela me paraît bien.
>
> Cela m'a l'air bien.

So, Google Translate had it right.

Comment: Toutes les expressions sont correctes, sauf "ça peut aller", qui n'a pas le même sens. ça peut aller is not "great" but it's "It's not really great, but I'll do with it, it's acceptable", while other expressions means something like "I'm ok", or "It's rather great".